# how to use the average value with values from 2 different sheets in a single spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

I'm using google-sheet.

How can I use the average with the information between 2 different sheets.
something like this maybe

```
=PROMEDIOA(nombre.de.hoja1.valor1: nombre.de.hoja2.valor1)
```

could someone give me a tip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, use the `=AVERAGE(value1, [value2, ...])` function.

For reference, see ["AVERAGE(values)"](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093615?hl=en).

Also look into [A1 Notation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts#a1_notation) for explanation on how to write ranges properly.

For example "nombre.de.hoja1.valor1" could be "Sheet1!A1" if "valor1" is in cell (range) "A1"